# cannot click on points in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector

I use OpenLayers 2.13.1 along with GeoServer and PostgreSQL

I have a code for a vector layer in my OpenLayers like so

```
//style for layer
var style_d = new OpenLayers.Style({
 'fillColor': '${p_color}',
 'fillOpacity': .8,
 'fontColor': 'black',
 'pointRadius': 8,
 'strokeColor': 'black',
 'strokeWidth': 1,
 'fontFamily': 'Arial',
 'fontSize': 10,
 'label': '${p_name}',
 'labelAlign': 'tc',
 'labelSelect': true,
 'labelXOffset': 4,
 'labelYOffset':4,
 },
 {
    context: {
        label:function(feature) {
            if(feature.attributes['p_name']) {
                return feature.attributes.p_name;       
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
 },
});


//style for layer - when click a geometry
var style_select = new OpenLayers.Style({
 'fillColor': '${p_color}',
 'fillOpacity': .4,
 'fontColor': 'black',
 'pointRadius': 5,
 'strokeColor': 'black',
 'strokeWidth': .5,
 'fontFamily': 'Arial',
 'fontSize': 10,
 'label': '${p_name}',
 'labelAlign': 'tc',
 'labelSelect': true,
 'labelXOffset': 4,
 'labelYOffset':4,
 },
 {
    context: {
        label:function(feature) {
            if(feature.attributes['p_name']) {
                return feature.attributes.p_name;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
 }
});

//Add a select feature control for pins
var select_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(mylayer, {multiple: false,toggle: true});

map.addControl(select_feature_control);

//Activate the control
select_feature_control.activate();

//do stuff when clicked
function selected_feature(event){
 document.getElementById("wesmes").innerHTML="Loading";
 sf = event.feature.fid;
 var sfs = sf.split(".");
 var sff = sfs[1];
 //call a function
}
```

Problem :

If there is a polygon or a line on the map I can click right on them and everything works.

If there is a point, I have to click outside the point, near at it, so it will be clicked and activate the `function selected_feature(event)` etc etc. If I click on the point, nothing happens

How can I fix this? Why is this happening? I think it is a problem of style. If you want I can provide more code

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Vector Layer array of elements and if you want doing something when one of the array elements is clicked, I'm doing this:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Valori", {
    eventListeners:{
        'featureselected':function(evt){                
              alert("Element clicked!");
        },
        'featureunselected':function(evt){
              //whatever
        }
    }
});
```

And it works fine.